# jQuery slider last to first transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

By default, when it's on the last slide the slider just scrolls to the left again to start over, as though it's an infinite loop. I want it to scroll back through all the slides and land on the first one again. Much like it does here (see the end of page: http://store.hogan.com/Hogan/IT/Traditional-20-15/p/HXM2540V600FMOG009). I used "jssor".com javascript to create it, taking carousel demo, and I can't add loop to the options, so I have to create another function but I don't know how to do it.

How can that be achieved?

Thank you, I'm new with this stuff.

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pacd4tL5/8/) if it can help you, but it doesn't work cause I've some external source that doesn't recognize. I'm sorry for the length of HTML and CSS codes, I had to take it like that for job.

This is my JS.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function Slider($) {

        var numOfCols = 0;
        var slideWidth = 0;

        var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        if (bodyWidth) {
            if (bodyWidth >= 770) {
                    numOfCols = 4;
                    slideWidth = 200;
                    console.log("desktop");
                }
                else if (bodyWidth >= 500) {
                    numOfCols = 2;
                    slideWidth = 230;
                    console.log("tablet");
                }
                else {
                    slideWidth = 285;
                    numOfCols = 1;
                    console.log("mobile");
                }
        }

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: true,
          $AutoPlaySteps: 1,
          $SlideDuration: 500,
          $SlideWidth: slideWidth,
          $SlideSpacing: 3,
          $Cols: numOfCols,
          $PauseOnHover:0,
          $Loop: 2,
          $otpCenter: true
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);


        $("#right").click(function() {
            jssor_1_slider.$Next();
        })

        $("#left").click(function() {
            jssor_1_slider.$Prev();
        });
    });
```

Comment: There are no images in you slider. It makes it hard to see what is happening when there is no content being moved by the slider.

Comment: There are images, but as I wrote, jsfiddle doesn't work because it doesn't take external sources. Anyway you can see the same slider on the Hogan link in the question. The difference is that my arrows don't work. @FrederickM.Rogers

Comment: My suggestion would be, find a slider that provides you with the desired effect rather then trying to make alterations to this one.

Comment: If you are stuck with that slider plugin then, try this one http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.WIIbaibhXqB

Comment: Idangero.us doesn't have the slider I want :) @ShinoyShaji

Answer (score 0):

Please set $Loop: 2 (rewind)

```
var jssor_1_options = {
  ...
  $Loop: 2,
  ...
};
```

Please check the **Loop** option here

- [Options - Jssor Slider Maker](http://www.jssor.com/help/options.html)
- [Options - Development](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html)

**Edit**

I checked your code and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pacd4tL5/8/).
The loop works. The problem is that the width of 'outer container' and 'slides' container is unexpected. Please change width of the 2 containers then.

```
<div id="jssor_1" data-slide="0" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:809px;height:350px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:809px;height:350px;overflow:hidden;">
```

Change width of the 2 container in the following code,

```
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (bodyWidth) {
        if (bodyWidth >= 770) {
            numOfCols = 4;
            slideWidth = 200;
            console.log("desktop");
        }
        else if (bodyWidth >= 500) {
            numOfCols = 2;
            slideWidth = 230;
            //width of the 2 containers should be 230 x 2 + 3 * 1 = 463
            console.log("tablet");
        }
        else {
            slideWidth = 285;
            numOfCols = 1;
            //width of the 2 containers should be 285
            console.log("mobile");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I try with $Loop: 2 but it doesn't work because this slider displays four columns (slides) at time and not only one. And another question: is it possible to put arrows outside slides div or not? @jssor

Comment: Ok arrows are ok, I still have problems with loop. I tried $Loop: 2 again but nothing. Please help me! I used carousel demo. @jssor

Comment: Please have a look http://www.jssor.com/jssordev/test/carousel-slider-rewind.slider

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but now it's working :D Thanks!

Comment: No ok isn't true, it works only on mobile, because I've dynamic num of columns depending on screens (mobile, tablet, desktop). For mobile I've only one column and it works. I upload my changed code. @jssor